# Stringstream when iterating through string doesnt work

Tags: c++, string, loops, iostream, sstream

So i want to use string stream to convert strings to integers.

assume everything is done with:

```
 using namespace std;
```

a basic case that seems to work is when I do this:

```
 string str = "12345";
 istringstream ss(str);
 int i;
 ss >> i;
```

that works fine.

However lets say I have a string defined as:

```
string test = "1234567891";
```

and I do:

```
int iterate = 0;
while (iterate):
    istringstream ss(test[iterate]);
    int i;
    ss >> i;
    i++;
```

this doesnt work as i want. essentially I was to idividually work on each element of the string as if it is a number, so i want to convert it to an int first, but i cant seem too. Could someone please help me?

the error i get is:

```
   In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:40:0,
             from validate.cc:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/istream:872:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Tp> std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&&, _Tp&)
 operator>>(basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&& __is, _Tp& __x)
 ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/istream:872:5: note:   template argument     deduction/substitution failed:
validate.cc:39:12: note:   ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’ is not derived from ‘std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>’
cout >> i >> endl;
```

Comment: How do you expect the stream to recognize where to break up the string into individual elements when there are no delimiters?

Comment: If you are using test[iterate] then you have an ASCII character that contains a digit.  To convert an ASCII character containing a digit to a number you can just subtract '0'.  `int i = test[iteratet] - '0'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two points you should understand.

1. If you use indexes to access string, you will get characters.
2. `istringstream` requires `string` as a parameter not characters to create object.

Now you in your code

```
    int iterate = 0;
     while (iterate):
    /* here you are trying to construct istringstream object using  
 which is the error you are getting*/
        istringstream ss(test[iterate]); 
        int i;
        ss >> i;
```

To correct this problem you can following approach

```
istringstream ss(str); 
int i;
while(ss>>i)
{
    std::cout<<i<<endl
}
```

Answer (score 4):

What you need is something like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::string str = "12345";
    std::stringstream ss(str);
    char c; // read chars
    while(ss >> c) // now we iterate over the stringstream, char by char
    {
        std::cout << c << std::endl;
        int i =  c - '0'; // gets you the integer represented by the ASCII code of i
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
}
```

<kbd>[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cda6ae6b8cf1250f)</kbd>

If you use `int c;` instead as the type of `c`, then `ss >> c` reads the whole integer `12345`, instead of reading it `char` by `char`. In case you need to convert the ASCII `c` to the integer that it represents, subtract `'0'` from it, like `int i = c - '0';`

**EDIT** As @dreamlax mentioned in the comment, if you just want to read the characters in the string and convert them to integers, there is no need to use a `stringstream`. You can just iterate over the initial string as

```
for(char c: str)
{
    int i = c - '0';
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: There's no point using a stringstream if you're just going to iterate over the individual characters in the string. May as well iterate over the string with iterators. `for (char c : str) std::cout << (c - '0');`

Comment: @dreamlax That's true, I guess I wrote the snippet above just to show how `stringstream` works.